# Change 7.3 KDE desktop text color

Tags: kde, desktop-environment

I have seen this question for GNOME, and for some other desktop environments, but none of those answers seem correct for this particular one.

I prefer a light desktop background so the white text is hard to read. Under GNOME I knew how to change this, but I thought I would try KDE. [EDIT: I have had the same question open for MacOS for years, and its bounty has gone unclaimed.]

Answer (score 0):

[This](https://www.ryananddebi.com/2016/09/14/kde-adjusting-the-look-and-feel-of-the-desktop-and-application-windows/) link appears to have a decent rundown of KDE theme settings including text color configuration.  The upshot is that you can find what you're looking for in System Settings -> Appearance.

Comment: I was unable to find the setting for this particular color anywhere in System Settings -> Appearance. Do you know which entry it is?